# Identity->Account Manage as Razor Component, consistent UI

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

After scaffolding Account Manage pages we get useful pages that allow basic operation on account (like password change). Unfortunately, all Account Manage pages are cshtml pages, not razor components. I know why that is, still, I would like to make it at least more consistent from UI point of view. For example, I would like to have a Profile edit page:

> /Identity/Account/Manage

available the same way as there is

> /counter

Without creating (and maintaining) two exactly the same menus on the top and left (one as razor component one as cshtml). Is that possible?